# C incomplete declarations

Tags: c, standards

I am looking for an explanation to the following statement regarding array declarators in this [book](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n802.pdf).

> The concept of composite types (§6.1.2.6) was introduced to provide
> for the accretion of information from incomplete declarations, such as
> array declarations with missing size, and function declarations with
> missing  prototype  (argument  declarations).    Type  declarators
> are  therefore  said  to  specify compatible types if they agree
> except for the fact that one provides less information of this sort
> than the other.
>
> The declaration of 0-length arrays is invalid, under the general
> principle of not providing for 0-length objects.  The only common use
> of this construct has been in the declaration of dynamically allocated
> variable-size arrays, such as

```
struct segment {
    short int    count;
    char    c[N];
};

struct segment * new_segment( const int length ) {
    struct segment * result;
    result = malloc( sizeof segment + (length-N) );
    result->count = length;
    return result;
}
```

> In such usage, N would be 0 and (length-N) would be written as length.
> But this paradigm works just as well, as written, if N is 1.

Specifically I am interested in what is the motivation of this paragraph and to understand that code snippet. Where does the `N` come from in the `new_segment` function?

Comment: It should be mentioned that the quoted part starts on page 61 of the linked PDF.

Comment: Re “what is the motivation of this paragraph”: The motivation of that paragraph is to explain why the concept of composite types was introduced. It is not clear what further you mean to ask in that regard.

Comment: `N` might be in `#define` macro

Comment: It seems like this is showing that the `new_segment` works whether `N` is `0` or `1`, when allocating a flexible array member at the end of a struct.

Answer (score 0):

> Where does the `N` come from in the `new_segment` function?

It is simply a placeholder in the text rather than intended to be an actual `N` in real code. As we see from this sentence:

> In such usage, N would be 0 and (length-N) would be written as length. But this paradigm works just as well, as written, if N is 1.

the text wishes to discuss two declarations of the `c` member, one with:

```
struct segment {
    short int    count;
    char    c[0];
};
```

and the other with:

```
struct segment {
    short int    count;
    char    c[1];
};
```

Writing them out requires more space, and also the following sample code for the `new_segment` function must be repeated. Further, it might be a bit less clear how the value of `N` changed `new_segment` if it were written as two separate instances with different literal constants rather than with `N` showing where the change occurs (although the affect is minor in any case).

The text is saying it is fairly easy for a programmer to use either 0 or 1 as the array size; it merely requires a minor adjustment when allocating space.

Comment: Is it just 0 or 1? The function looks like it can be any number there.